# Python Mutiprocessing Counter update

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am using python multiprocessing to call a function called "sql_fetch" and that function should update variable count as many times it iterate over my list (which is "test_propid_entid" ) to determine how many time I get good data from my query . here query_randomizer if my function call which generates the query and I just want to print results in count variable at end of multiprocessing call to determine how many times pandas dataframe returned results (i.e. how many time query returned records)  :  How can I achieve this ? count always prints 1 for me because it resets the value with each call 
I used below in multiprocessing :

```
from tqdm import tqdm

start_dt = time()
multi =[]
with tqdm(total=len(test_propid_entid)) as pbar:
    for sub_prop_entid in test_propid_entid:
        t_sub = multiprocessing.Process(target=sql_fetch, args=(sub_prop_entid,))
        pbar.update()
        multi.append(t_sub)
        t_sub.start()
    for a in multi:
        a.join()
print('TOTAL TIME: ' ,time() - start_dt)
```

And I want to call sql_fetch function to get data from Oracle query engine :

```
import pandas as pd
def sql_fetch(sub_prop_entid):
    count = 0 
    data= pd.read_sql(query_randomizer(
        sub_prop_entid[0], sub_prop_entid[1], arg1, arg2,), engine)
    num_records = len(pd.DataFrame(data).index)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    if num_records > 0:
        count += 1
        print( "# Of Records............: " ,num_records , '\n')
        df.insert(0,'# Of Records',num_records)
        df.insert(1,'Exec Time',tot)
        display(df)
    print ("Records with good data", count)
```

Comment: Please edit the code in your question so it is a [mre] - that means anyone should be able to paste your code into a file and run it __without adding anything__ and see the behaviour you are having a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand the difference betw. multiprocessing and multithreading. I believe the latter is a right way for your task.

Multiprocessing in python allows you to run a task parallel in multiple "CPU"s, which implies that any variable, data or connection CANNOT be pickled (i.e. shared). Think of every process as a whole new python program - and what you are trying to do is to share a variable between different python programs.

So, try to go with multithreading and set counter as a global variable.

```
import multithreading
global counter
for sub_prop_entid in test_propid_entid:
    t_sub = multithreading.Thread(target=sql_fetch, args=(sub_prop_entid,))
    multi.append(t_sub)
    t_sub.start()
for a in multi:
    a.join()
```

Comment: Understand but your answers are incomplete .. Can you complete that with update on "def sql_fetch" how to use that counter global variable to that function and print that value . That will help other reader too .